# To say Kaddish at the cemetery after burial, do the mourners count as part of the minyan?

Tags: mourning-aveilus, kaddish, funeral-burial-levaya

I understand that *onenim* cannot be counted as part of the minyan. Thus, at the cemetery, when saying the Kaddish can they be counted as part of the minyan or do we need 10 others besides them?

Answer (score 2):

As explained by my rav, once the burial has completed and the body is covered, the status of the onenim immediately changes from *onen* to *avel*. At this point, they are counted as part of the minyan.

Comment: Some hold that once preparations for the kevurah have been completed, the bereaved no longer have the din of onenim